# Changing of meaning of "piuttosto che" over the years

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, adverbs

When I was a kid, I learnt at school that 'piuttosto che' was used as follows

> "Piuttosto che venire con voi me ne sto a casa",

whose meaning was 'instead of', a contrast between two mutual excluding items.

Over time my feeling is that the meaning was changing  and the expression 'piuttosto che' took the meaning of 'oppure', in the inclusive sense of the conjunction (inclusive *or*, meaning one or the other, but also both of the items).

So in this sense it is nowadays very common to hear things like

> "Essi si trovano a Roma piuttosto che a Milano",

where the meaning would be "they go to Rome or to Milan or to both of the cities".

According to [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piuttosto/) and [Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/uso-piuttosto-valore-disgiuntivo), it is an improper usage.

I personally do not like this usage and my idea is that it seems to be an import/export operation from the English language. 
Indeed 'rather than' translation is 'anziché', but the direct translation is 'piuttosto che', now used also in Italian with the meaning of 'anziché' ('oppure').

My question is:
Is this usage theory supported in some way?

Comment: It is a horrible distortion invented by some consulting companies based in Milan. Then it spread nationwide like a disease.

Answer (score 10):

The question is about the current usage of the conjunction.

It concerns the usage of *piuttosto che*, originally intended as the Latin **aut** (the exclusive or) in the meaning of the Latin **vel** (the inclusive or).

I agree, and my opinion seems to be supported by what the two sources you refer to say, that this second usage is completely incorrect. That's because it leads to an unresolved ambiguity and there is no reason why it should be used like this.
The inclusive or could indeed be expressed by other means.

As the Crusca says, this usage is starting to be very popular (it also says it comes from television speech). To me, it sounds like you use it in the “vel“ sense if you want to sound intellectual and you are not (this means that you don't really know the original meaning).

It's actually a very interesting linguistic phenomenon, provided it will become the majority usage (overcoming the original one), because popular culture can modify the overall language. For the time being, I don't feel like using ‘piuttosto che’ in the second sense, because I was taught the original one and didn't forget it.

Answer (score 7):

Even though I completely agree that this usage is erroneous, it's an interesting question about *how* and *why* this usage has started.
There are several studies on the topic, most of them listed [here](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piuttosto_che). In particular, Carla Bazzanella e Mirella Cristofori, "[Piuttosto che e le alternative non preferenziali. Un mutamento in atto?](http://revistas.ucm.es/index.php/CFIT/article/view/CFIT9898110267A)", Cuadernos de Filología Italiana, 1998, 5, 267-278, state the following:

> Come affermano Mondadori e D’Agostino (1997,3.1): «A volte, affermando P oppure Q intendiamo affermare non solo che almeno una tra P e Q é vera, ma anche che non sono entrambe.» In questo caso, che si avvicina all’uso in questione di *piuttosto che*, possiamo anche ravvisare un esempio di quello che Palazzi-Folena regista come seconda entrata per *oppure*: «2. o anche: *puoi trovarlo in quel negozio oppure in quello di fronte.* » Se sostituissimo infatti in questo esempio *oppure* con *piuttosto che* ci troveremmo di fronte ad un esempio simile a quelli riportati: *puoi trovarlo in quel negozio piuttosto che in quello di fronte*.
>   Ci teniamo a dichiarare esplicitamente che al nostro orecchio continua a
>   sembrare un comportamento anomalo, e che se noi proferissimo: *puoi trovarlo in
>   quel negozio piuttosto che in quello di fronte*, nel nostro idioletto indicheremmo
>   che le possibilità di reperimento di quel dato oggetto sono molto più alte nel
>   primo negozio citato che non in quello di fronte. II contesto linguistico serve
>   però, come negli esempi citati, ad indicare un alto uso di *piuttosto che*, appunto
>   di «introduttore neutro di alternative divergenti» ma presentate come paritarie o,
>   più in generale, di segnalare una molteplicità di possibilità.

Answer (score 1):

This is more and more common and it drives me crazy. I would not use it but it is useful to know that some speakers might be using it in the wrong way.

Comment: Welcome to [Italian.SE]! Here at StackExchange we expect users to provide reasonably long and detailed answer, which feature both facts (preferably sourced) and opinions: for an example of a good answer, look at [the one martina gave](http://italian.stackexchange.com/a/1413/591).

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello sorry.  It was not clear what  the question was. So I tried to give an advice on the use of the word: don't use it as inclusive or  but be aware that some use it exactly that way.

Answer (score 1):

In the [spring 2017 issue of the journal *Oblio*](https://www.academia.edu/33548435/Medaglia_F._2017_Recensione_a_Elio_Vittorini._Si_diverte_tanto_a_tradurre_Lettere_a_Lucia_Rodocanachi_1933-43._In_Oblio_n._VII-25_pp._170-171?auto=download&email_work_card=download-paper) (*Osservatorio Bibliografico della Letteratura Italiana Otto-novecentesca*), Claudio Giovanardi makes a review of the article "«Piuttosto che» disgiuntivo in Gadda" by Gualberto Alvino, published in 2016 in *Studi linguistici italiani*.

It is mentioned that the first one to interprete this phenomenon, Ornella Castellani Pollidori, had traced its origin in the Lombard and Piedmontese bourgeoisie and that thence, from the nineties of the last century, and thanks to the complicity of the mass media (whose role in the diffusion of this kind of innovations is decisive), such use of "piuttosto che" has spread to the rest of the Peninsula:

> Uno dei fenomeni sintattici più dibattuti dell’italiano odierno è senza dubbio l’uso innovativo (una sorta di mutazione genetica) della locuzione congiuntiva *piuttosto che*, la quale, oltre all’originario valore avversativo/comparativo, ha assunto anche quello disgiuntivo di *o*, *oppure*. Contro tale estensione d’uso si sono pronunciati numerosi studiosi, ma anche molti interpreti del sentimento linguistico comune, tanto che sono state indette vere e proprie crociate contro il nuovo *piuttosto che* perfino nei *social network*. Il convincimento di tutti, ad ogni modo, è che si tratti di un uso confinato nel parlato. La prima interprete del fenomeno, Ornella Castellani Pollidori (opportunamente citata da Alvino nel suo contributo), ne aveva rintracciato l’origine nei salotti della
> buona borghesia lombarda e piemontese; di lì, a partire dagli anni Novanta dello scorso secolo, e grazie alla complicità dei mezzi di comunicazione di massa (il cui ruolo nella diffusione dei tratti innovativi è decisivo), la locuzione risemantizzata si sarebbe diffusa nel resto della Penisola.

Interestingly enough, Alvino has studied some occurrences of this use of "piuttosto che" in some books by Carlo Emilio Gadda, occurrences that are quoted below:

> Ora Gualberto Alvino, inesausto indagatore di personaggi scomodi della letteratura italiana (basti
> pensare ai suoi fondamentali contributi su Pizzuto), servendosi delle concordanze gaddiane allestite da Maria Luigia Ceccotti e Manuela Sassi, ha potuto rinvenire l’uso di *piuttosto che* disgiuntivo in
> alcune opere di Carlo Emilio Gadda: cinque attestazioni (su un totale di trentaquattro occorrenze della locuzione), la più antica delle quali risale al 1928 (e precisamente al saggio *La molteplicità dei significati del reale*). Alvino riporta i brani relativi e non vi è dubbio che nelle cinque occasioni
> siamo di fronte al *piuttosto che* disgiuntivo:
>
> > Un sistema si dice che funziona bene (come p.e. una macchina) se ha eliminato gruppi di relazioni... come dire?... imperfetti no, che [*recte*: ché] tutto è, e nulla è perfetto piuttosto che imperfetto... ma gruppi di relazioni per così esprimermi estranei alla sua ‘idea’ e che ne ha ‘tirati in barca’ altri, conferenti a questa idea. (*Meditazione milanese* [1928], in *Opere di Carlo Emilio Gadda*, ed. diretta da Dante Isella, Milano, Garzanti, 1988-1993, vol. v. *Scritti vari e postumi*, pp. 615-894 [p. 754]);
> >
> > avevano buttato là con efficace noncuranza [...] quella domandina impreveduta e poi preveduta e aspettata
> > della sciarpa: e com’era, e di che colore era, e s’era di stoffa, o di maglia a mano, piuttosto che a macchina.
> > (*Quer pasticciaccio brutto de via Merulana* [1946-47], in *Opere*, cit., vol. II. *Romanzi e racconti*, pp. 11-276 [p. 188]);
> >
> > Non rimasero che due persone, convogliabili verso il boudoir: il capitano in complet, «bien que quelque peu démodé», e la già miss Bargon, ora Fraülein. Era, costei, un’alta e vigorosa donnona, che non aveva detto una parola, a tavola: lo sguardo leggermente peso, imbambolato, come per un leggero esoftalmo, benché non
> > portasse occhiali, e poi la gola piena, rigonfia, la pelle cereolattea, concorrevano alla edificazione, per accenni, di una facies basedowoide. Neri i capelli, d’una estrema e tacita riservatezza, non si capiva se il suo
> > volto e il suo gentile guardare si applicassero alla meditazione morale, all’analisi psicologica, o al calcolo: o
> > a tutt’e tre. Quando si soffermava, lo sguardo un po’ triste, sul gilè piuttosto che sul viso del capitano, sembrava palesare un certo imbarazzo e insieme un certo disinteresse, una timida o malinconica perplessità.
> > Aveva l’aria di non riuscire a capire che cosa fosse un capitano. (*Socer generque* [1947], in *Opere*, vol. II,
> > cit., pp. 791-813 [p. 799]);
> >
> > La preoccupazione maggiore di Beniamino, d’altronde, non derivava dal fatto che la sua Sostanza andasse a sbattere, in un giorno lontano, consumati tutti i secoli dei secoli, in testa ad uno piuttosto che ad altro marginale o addirittura estrinseco erede o Venarvaghi o Golliati: ma dall’atroce rischio che ad ogni nuovo accoppiamento di eredi, suberedi, ed eredi probabili Ella correva, di sminuirsi un po’ per volta.
> > (*Accoppiamenti giudiziosi* [1957-58], in *Opere*, vol. II, cit., pp. 591-920 [p. 901]);
> >
> > I rami (di un pero, di un sorbo) vengono chiamati i legni, ancor oggi: e legno egualmente il tronco, il fusto di
> > un alberello. Talché mi si riduce a mente il vergiliano oleastro «nautis olim venerabile lignum», venerato un tempo dalla gente del mare, nonché il sorriso di Orazio maliziosetto là là dove Priapo, una specie di
> > Pinocchio latino, racconta che Geppetto faber (= falegname), incerto se fabbricare di un certo tronco un dio piuttosto che uno sgabello, si risolvette pel dio. (*Il latino nel sangue* [1959], in *Opere*, cit., vol. III. *Saggi, giornali e favole I*, pp. 1151-61 «p. 1160]).

It is also mentioned that some other written occurences of "piuttosto che" with this meaning have been found in texts from 1906 and from 1851:

> Così come il medesimo valore hanno i due *piuttosto che* rintracciati in altrettanti testi ancor più antichi (l’uno, politico, del 1851; l’altro, filosofico, del 1906).

This is what the author explains about the reasons that took Gadda to use "piuttosto che" with this meaning and about the value of these finds in general:

> Cosa ci dicono tali reperti? Innanzi tutto che l’incubazione di un fenomeno linguistico è talvolta molto lunga. Gadda, sensibile scrutatore di tutte le pieghe linguistiche del suo tempo, non si fa scrupolo di mettere per iscritto un vezzo che evidentemente aveva colto sulla bocca dei suoi interlocutori lombardi e che, probabilmente, adottava egli stesso conversando. Il vezzo, rimasto
> circoscritto per decenni agli usi colti dei settentrionali (spesso insofferenti, va detto, rispetto alla norma di base toscana dell’italiano), è poi progressivamente debordato nel parlato (colto) degli altri
> italiani, forse anche per il prestigio tributato alle varietà regionali settentrionali (ampiamente rappresentate alla radio, in televisione e nella Rete). In secondo luogo che il caso di *piuttosto che*
> non è isolato nel panorama dell’italiano odierno.

Finally, about the reasons for the rejection of this use of *piuttosto che*, the author says:

> Infine che l’avversione per il *piuttosto che* disgiuntivo (avversione condivisa, beninteso, dallo stesso Alvino) è motivata non tanto da un puro spirito conservatore, ma dal fatto che la collisione col valore tradizionale della locuzione può creare un serio imbarazzo nell’interpretazione dell’intero enunciato.